# Is there a way to add characters based on a variable?

Tags: python, count, text-processing

I'm making a text-based game about Hangman and so far I have 10 words with different amounts of characters in each word. The lowest character count is three, so I'm planning to put in three underscores at the start for me to be able to add underscores after the string.

I have a variable set up, called `wordPlayingLength` which counts up an integer based on the amount of characters in the word that has been selected through a random statement. My question is if there's a way to add underscores that matches up with the word's length in characters?

```
if (randomNumber == 10):
    wordPlaying = str("Didgeridoo") ## states the word being played
    wordPlayingLength = int(len(wordPlaying)) ## calculates the character length of the word being played
    print(str(wordPlayingLength) + " letters!")

    underscoreCount = (wordPlayingLength)
    print("_ _ _ " + ) ## this is where I got stuck, no idea here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is your program containing the logic I think you're describing:

```
if randomNumber == 10:
    wordPlaying = "Didgeridoo"
    print("{}  letters!".format(len(wordPlaying)))
    print(' '.join('_' * len(wordPlaying)))
```

I've removed some unnecessary sets of parentheses and uses of `str()` and `int()`.  Since calling `len()` of a string or list is a constant-time operation, there's no need to save use a variable to store the length here.

The key behaviors you need to know about are:

- [`str.join()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.join), which takes the elements of an iterable and makes a string out of them by interleaving the elements of the iterable with the contents of the string it's called on.
- The [integer n * sequence s](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#common-sequence-operations) operator returns the sequence you get if you add `n` copies of `s` together.

Answer (score 1):

In Python, you can multiply a string by an integer to make repetition:

```
>>> num_of_underscores = 9
>>> num_of_underscores * "_"
'_________'
```

If you wanted spaces between the underscores, you could do something like

```
>>> " ".join("_" * num_of_underscores)
'_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _'
```

where you multiply an array with a single underscore by an integer to get that many of them.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly,
You don't need `wordPlaying = str("Didgeridoo")` just `wordPlaying = "Didgeridoo"`

and `wordPlayingLength = int(len(wordPlaying))` just `wordPlayingLength = len(wordPlaying)`

Secondly,
to repeate string, you can use `' _ ' * wordPlayingLength`